# How I can use local package in golang?

Tags: go

Here are two `.go` files.

```
├── lib.go
└── main.go
```

The `lib.go` has a package `libtest`.

```
$ cat lib.go 

package libtest

import (
    "fmt"
)

func TestLibFunc() {
    fmt.Println("This is test library function")
}
```

The `main.go` has a package `main`.

```
$ cat main.go
package main

import (
    "libtest"
)

func main() {
    libtest.TestLibFunc()
}
```

When I tried to build them, but it's failed.

```
$ go build *.go
can't load package: package main: found packages libtest (lib.go) and main (main.go) in /Users/dev/work/tmp/local-package
```

How can I use local packages in `main` package?

Comment: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: You can`t declare difаerent package name in one package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put each package in a separate sub-directory. So your directory structure so put lib.go in `project/lib` and main.go in `project/cmd`. It should then work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a separate package `libtest` and put `lib.go` there. Then you should give the full path of `libtest` otherwise your import right now searches for `$GOPATH/src/libtest` or `/usr/local/Cellar/go/<version>` which doesn't exist.

So you should give `import project/libtest`